# Two level url rewrite with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need something like this `index.php?page=home` to be `/home`

and

`index.php?page=products&cat=chairs` to be `/products/chairs`

What would be the mod_rewrite rule to achieve this?

### Edited

I have other pages than home, so my full content of .htaccess file is now

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule   ^/products(:/([^/]+))?   /index.php?page=products&cat=$1 [L]
```

But when I navigate to `/products/chairs` I get a "Object not found" error.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   ^/home/?$                /index.php?page=home [L]
RewriteRule   ^/products(:/([^/]+))?   /index.php?page=products&cat=$1 [L]
```

It rewrites both `/home` and `/home/`, both `/products` and `/products/` (you didnt specify which was your intended behavior); beware that you will get an empty `cat` parameter in those cases.

EDIT: this is a tested .htaccess, with R=301 left on it to see rewriting result, with both .htaccess and index.php in same directory (webroot in my case):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$          index.php?page=$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^products/([^/]+)?/?   index.php?page=products&cat=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: the second one doesn't work. I get "Object not found". I also have other page than home - please see edited description for my htacess file content.

Comment: you may need to remove the leading slash in */index.php* (as for first rule) if that file is not in the virtualhost root

Comment: please try with my edited snippet, leaving R=301 to check if it is working right

Comment: I get the page redirected to C:\xampp...index.php?page=products and I get Access forbidden. I think I am giving up. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?page=(products)&cat=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2 [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?page=(home)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L]

RewriteRule   ^(products)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=(products)&cat=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule   ^(home)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Change `R=302` to `R=301` after you verify it's working fine for you.